# Prove that when $d$ is in $\mathbb{Q} \setminus\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ is not a finitely generated abelian group.

Tags: abstract-algebra

When $d$ is in $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}] = \{a_0 + a_1 \sqrt{d} \mid a_0, a_1 \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

However, when $d$ is in $\mathbb{Q} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$, I cannot prove it.

Of course, when I see an example, I can understand that this is not a finitely generated abelian group, but I want to know the proof in general.

Answer (score 2):

This follows much in the same way that one shows $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a finitely generated abelian group.

Consider $\sqrt{d}^2 = \pm d \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$. Then there is $\frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b) = 1$, and $0 < a < b$.

Let $\{a_1, \dots, a_n\}$ be a proposed generating set of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ as an abelian group under addition. Then for every $m$ there exists $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\sum_i \lambda_i a_i = \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^m$.

Consider what the largest possible denominator of $\sum_i \lambda_ia_i$ can be in reduced form in terms of the denominators of the integers that appear in the $a_i$, and note that there is always an $m$ so that $\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^m$ has a larger (reduced form) denominator.

Comment: These generators are from $\mathbb{Q}$, right?